# how to link a 2.4 blender file to the 2.7 blender version?

Tags: materials, objects, linked-data

I have tried linking older blender files to the newest version of blender and I get a warning saying that it is too old and it will not work with the recent version.

Comment: When I tried appending and linking from a ~.blend file created with version 2.45, I got a slightly different warning message than you relate: "Linking or appending from a very old blend file format (2.45.0), no animation conversion will be done! You may want to re-save your lib file with current Blender". No warning is generated if I open the old version file with the current version of Blender. So that's what I'd do, and then save the file with a new name.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to Save the old blender files into a new blender file?

Try and open a new file in your newest version of blender. Then, just append every file from the Old blender file( of which you have problems linking) to the new blender file. Save that new file, and that should do it! It should work...